# Boost.Regex delimiter parsing

Tags: c++, regex, boost, delimiter

This is rather a quick question, I just couldn't find it in the boost documentation nor any other boost regex examples/tutorials.

Suppose I want to tokenize a string using this implementation:

```
boost::regex re("[\\sXY]+");
std::string s;

while (std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
  boost::sregex_token_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), re, -1);
boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
  while (i != j) {
     std::cout << *i++ << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that the delimiter expression won't be iterated. I also need the delimiter string. How can I make sure of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to also iterate through the delimiters in addition to iterating through the tokens. Wouldn't it be sufficient to create another token iterator which looks for tokens identified by your regex?

```
 boost::sregex_token_iterator i(s.begin(), s.end(), re, -1);

 boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
 //now find the tokens that match the regex -> the delimiters
 boost::sregex_token_iterator begin(s.begin(), s.end(), re), end;
 while (i != j)
   {
     std::cout << *i++ << " ";
     if( begin != end)
       {
         std::cout << "(delimiter = " << *begin++ << ") ";
       }
   }
```

Comment: Yes exactly, but now are the delimiters and other tokens not in the right order... I want to split a string, but the delimiters must be among the other tokens AND **must** be in the right order.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're completely right! Every token is delimited by a delimiter.. Thank you!